# Intersection of open orbits in homogeneous space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, homogeneous-spaces

Let $G$ be a simple complex algebraic group. Let $P(\alpha_i),P(\alpha_k)$ be maximal standard parabolic subgroups of $G$ associated to simple roots $\alpha_i,\alpha_k$ in the root system associated to the Lie algebra of $G$. Note that there exists a Borel subgroup $B$ contained in $P(\alpha_i) \cap P(\alpha_k)$. Following Perrin, ([here the paper](http://relaunch.hcm.uni-bonn.de/fileadmin/perrin/AIF.pdf)), we can define an open $P(\alpha_i)$-orbit in the homogeneous space $G/P(\alpha_k)$ as
$$
O^+:=P(\alpha_i)w_0P(\alpha_k)/P(\alpha_k),
$$
where $w_0$ is a representative element in the class of the longest element in the Weyl group associated to the Lie algebra of $G$.

Following Borel and Tits ([here the paper](http://www.numdam.org/item/PMIHES_1965__27__55_0/)), we have that
$$
w_0^{-1}P(\alpha_i)w_0=P^-(\iota(\alpha_i)),
$$
where $P^-(\iota(\alpha(i))$ is the opposite of the standard parabolic subgroup associated to the simple root $\iota(\alpha_i))$ and $\iota$ is the permutation of simple roots given by $w_0$. Suppose that $\alpha_i$ is such that $\iota(\alpha_i)=\alpha_i$ (for example, $\alpha_2$ in the root system of type $\mathrm A_3$). We also have that
$$
O^-:=P^-(\alpha_i) P(\alpha_k)/P(\alpha_k) \subset G/P(\alpha_k)
$$
is an open orbit. In fact, consider the isomorphism $L_{w_0}: G/P(\alpha_k) \to G/P(\alpha_k)$ given by the left multiplication by $w_0$, then its restriction to $O^-$ produces
$$
L_{w_0}(O^-)=w_0P^-(\alpha_i)P(\alpha_k)/P(\alpha_k)=w_0w_0^{-1}P(\alpha_i)w_0P(\alpha_k)/P(\alpha_k)=O^+.
$$
Since both $O^+$ and $O^-$ are open orbits in $G/P(\alpha_k)$, their intersection is non-empty.

**Question:**
The intersection can be written as
$$
O^- \cap O^+=\left\{g P(\alpha_k): g \in P:=w_0^{-1} P(\alpha_i)w_0P(\alpha_k) \cap P(\alpha_i)w_0P(\alpha_k)\right\},
$$
how can we describe $P$ as a subset of $G$?